# Chrome is requesting Laravel page as ajax request not as page request

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, laravel, vue.js

My app loads a laravel page and then I use Vue js to request some additional info on certain pages for. 
In my laravel methods I use

```
if($request->ajax()){
    return response()->json([])//json array
}
return view()//my view
```

However on google chrome when I go to a new page, and then press back to load the last page (or Forward), I am sent the Json response from laravel

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

It works fine on Firefox and Epiphany

Comment: I have tried it in incognito mode as well in case there was an extension causing it but same thing

Comment: this isn't a laravel issue but issue with vue js. the push state isn't working properly.

Comment: @itachi it loads the json instead of the page so it can't be a Vue js error

Comment: @itachi, I removed the Vuejs script from the page and had no issue, any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: So to fix  this for now I just used jquery outside of my vue instance and passed the data in.  if there is a fix for I would love to know!